# NullPointerException when calling data.getData inside OnActivityResult()?

Tags: android, android-camera, mediastore

I'm trying to display the path of a saved picture taken by the camera, by calling

```
`data.getdata`
```

inside a Toast, but the App crashs. I also tried `data.getDataString` but it did not solve

any thing.

Code:

```
@Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent imageIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            File imagesFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "My Images");
            imagesFolder.mkdirs();
            File image = new File(imagesFolder, "img01");
            Uri uriSavedImage = Uri.fromFile(image);
            imageIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uriSavedImage);
            startActivityForResult(imageIntent,CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    });
}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if ((requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE) && (resultCode == RESULT_OK)) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Image Saved To: "+data.getData(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Comment: have a look at this: http://achorniy.wordpress.com/2010/04/26/howto-launch-android-camera-using-intents/

Answer (score 1):

Get the extras bundle from your intent, there is the resulting data accessible.

```
Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
```

Don't forget a null check, since I'm in the impression that the tag "data" is not valid on all phones.

edit: Made code more precise, i.e. giving the exact solution here.

Answer (score 1):

[Camera Intent result woes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6271306/camera-intent-result-woes)

looked through this..

have you tried data.getExtras().get(TAG); ?

Comment: the method .get(TAG) is undefined

Comment: TAG is what you have defined as the TAG ie in this case MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT

Answer (score 0):

Also use, `data.getData().toString()`

`data.getData().toString()` should work. But, it won't actually give you the actual path of the image stored. It'll rather give you an `URI` of that image. You'll need to parse that uri using.

```
public String getRealPathFromURI(String uriString) {
    try {
        String[] proj = { MediaStore.Image.Media.DATA};
        Log.d("First", proj[0]);
        Cursor cursor = managedQuery(Uri.parse(uriString), proj, null, null, null);
        int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Image.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor.getString(column_index);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "Alas!";
}
```

Comment: Check my updated answer. Especially that, `data.getData().toString()` part.

Comment: but i want to display the path only when requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE) && (resultCode == RESULT_OK

Comment: Oops sorry. I did not see that correctly. I thought both the cases are for `requestCode`. Editing back my answer.

Comment: but still the App crashs!! any help would be highly appreciated